# REST @DeleteMapping - Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager

Tags: spring, rest

When i use DELETE in postman on adress http://localhost:8081/api/data/removedata/1

i get a message response saying:"Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead",

this is the java code

```
    @DeleteMapping("/removedata/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity deleteData(@PathVariable String id) {
        long remInt = Long.parseLong(id);
        Data dataRem = em.find(Data.class, remInt);
          em.getTransaction().begin();
          em.remove(dataRem);
          em.getTransaction().commit();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("Data removed"));
    }
```

What am i doing wrong? ps im a novice still struggling with the basics.

Comment: Where does this em EntityManager come from? And you should definitely read about Transaction Support of the Spring Framework https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction

Comment: it was created above the @DeleteMapping like this:

```
 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager em;
```

However i solved the issue, forgot to add @Transactional ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by adding @Transactional like so:

```
    @Transactional
    @DeleteMapping("/removedata/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity deleteData(@PathVariable String id) {
        long remInt = Long.parseLong(id);
        Data dataRem = em.find(Data.class, remInt);
          em.getTransaction().begin();
          em.remove(dataRem);
          em.getTransaction().commit();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("Data removed"));
    }
```